# How do I use a mixin param in a each loop?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to create a BEM spacing helper mixin that contains the name of the screen in the class name. An example output: `.marSm0 .marSm0__t .marSm0__b .marSm0__x`

```
$emMd0: 1em !default;
$emMd1: 1.5em !default;
$emMd2: 2em !default;
$emMd3: 4em !default;

$emMdSpacing: ($emNone, $emMd0, $emMd1, $emMd2, $emMd2 );


@mixin spacingHelper($screenSize, $spacingValues){
    @each $space in $spaceValues {
      .mar#{screenSize}#{$space} {
            margin: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .mar#{screenSize}#{$space}__x {
            margin-left: #{$space}rem;
            margin-right: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .mar#{screenSize}#{$space}__y {
            margin-top: #{$space}rem;
            margin-bottom: #{$space}rem;

        }

        .mar#{screenSize}#{$space}__l {
            margin-left: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .mar#{screenSize}#{$space}__r {
            margin-right: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .mar#{screenSize}#{$space}__b {
            margin-bottom: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .mar-#{screenSize}#{$space}__t {
            margin-top: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .pad#{screenSize}#{$space} {
            padding: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .pad#{screenSize}#{$space}__x {
            padding-left: #{$space}rem;
            padding-right: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .pad#{screenSize}#{$space}__y {
            padding-top: #{$space}rem;
            padding-bottom: #{$space}rem;

        }

        .pad#{screenSize}#{$space}__l {
            padding-left: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .pad#{screenSize}#{$space}__r {
            padding-right: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .pad#{screenSize}#{$space}__b {
            padding-bottom: #{$space}rem;
        }

        .pad#{screenSize}#{$space}__t {
            padding-top: #{$space}rem;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `$screenSize` mixin argument isn't working in the each loop. How do I fix this? I'm sure if the each loop is having a scope issue. [Code](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/abJjBgJ?editors=1100)

*Ignore for question validation*

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis vehicula tellus, id ultrices massa. Suspendisse dignissim in odio non rutrum. Vestibulum dapibus eget eros at aliquet. Quisque vitae vulputate massa, ac laoreet orci. Vestibulum vestibulum ante quis eros sollicitudin euismod. Cras eget orci turpis.

Comment: You just have a typo l18 in your codepen, you've written `$margiMd0` instead of `$marginMd0`, see the missing `n` ?

Comment: You also have a typo l68... You might want to check your code.